# database manager for android where i can add,update and do all other option like phpmyadmin in php

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Is there any database manager for android where I can add,update and do all other option like phpmyadmin in PHP.

I just want to easy my work where I can add database manually without firing query.just help me because I have lots of data to insert and if I do it manually by firing query than its take around 2 months.

Thank you

Comment: You can try SQLite Expert (http://www.sqliteexpert.com/) & also one mozilla firefox plugin - SQLite Manager (https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)

Answer (score 0):

There are some GUI based tools available, you can use either of any:

- [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/), firefox plugin
- [SQLite Expert professional](http://www.sqliteexpert.com/download.html)

FYI, there are 2 ways to integrate database in android application:

1. Create database from scratch using code
2. Use existing database (i.e. created using SQLite manager or any other third ,party tools), but here you have to write code to copy database into your application.

Search more about these 2 options and you would get plenty of resources!

Comment: can u share link please